# ANN: Perceptron performance in determining point positions

Tags: swift, neural-network, perceptron

So I'm starting with machine learning and Artificial Neural Networks and I found this article [The Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-10-neural-networks/) that introduces to Artificial Neural Networks and the idea of a Perceptron.

Through the article they show you how to create a Perceptron that is able  to discriminate between points positioned above or below a line based on the function:

> f(x) = 2x + 1

I developed my own Perceptron in Swift and used XCode Playgrounds to illustrate my Perceptron performance.

The perceptron takes 3 inputs: x, y and bias (always 1). The weights of the 3 inputs are generated at random, and after some training they are adjusted.

This first graphic shows the value of the first weight over trainings. As you can see, the value stabilizes at the end, and this is a proof that the Perceptron learned to discriminate points:
[image]

The second graphic represents the function line and all the training points (selected at random). The green points are the ones that the Perceptron predicted well, whereas the red ones are the wrong predictions:

[image]

As you can see, almost all of the red dots are situated in the inverse function:

> f(x) = -2x - 1

My question is why this line of error dots appear. I thought that at a certain point all the weights would be stabilized and that the Perceptron performance would be 100%, but it never does. Is this because of a code bug or ANN always have this tiny interval of error?

Any explanation will be welcomed, although keep in mind that I'm a newbie at ML and ANN.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't you think you could unintentionally change the sign of the input or output data while working with the ANN? Or it may be just a drawing issue.

Comment: I thought about the input sign, but i can't find anything. About the drawing issue, I'm afraid it's not the case. If you look at the first graph, when the weight stabilizes, there are still some variations to its value, and I think this modifications are the representation of the line of red dots (if there weren't this error dots, the weight value would be totally stable). Again, this is my guess and I'm not totally sure.

Comment: May be you can provide us with some code? If it's big to be included in the question, use https://gist.github.com/ or something alike.

Comment: It would be great to have a look at your code. I'm wondering if it could be something about how you compare the output from the perceptron with the target value (red vs. green)...

Comment: Also: What is your first diagram? Is it the weight for the `x`-input? Why does it decrease like that? Do you have the y-values for that graph? (you have only 3 weights, right?)